# Error while trying to install zsteg

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

While trying to install [zsteg](https://github.com/zed-0xff/zsteg) on Ubuntu I encounter the following error:

```
$ sudo gem install zsteg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing zsteg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rainbow-2.2.2/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 mkrf_conf.rb

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rainbow-2.2.2/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -rubygems /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rainbow-2.2.2 RUBYLIBDIR=/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rainbow-2.2.2
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake (LoadError)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rainbow-2.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rainbow-2.2.2/gem_make.out
```

ruby2.3, ruby-sec and rake are installed

and also tried:

```
gem update --system
```

Please help.

Comment: Why do you call `gem` with `sudo`?

Comment: because if not: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.`

Comment: Does anyone know?